# Caching with different DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

I'm using a UnitOfWork pattern with Generic Repositories. I implemented a memory caching whenever the database is queried. Loading records are completely fine. The issue I have is if I were to create a new record that instantiates a new UnitOfWOrk which differs from any property used from the case.

For example
MemoryCache has a List of Ethnicity Stored

pseudoCode

I create a new Person and set Person.Ethnicity = MemoryCache.Ethnicities.First(x => x.type == type);

when I try to save this, it provides me this error `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker`. I can get rid of it if I don't instantiate a new UnitOfWork.

So now I'm in a bit of a predicament, do I use a singleton Dbcontext? It could get very heavy and slow overtime, or do I just get rid of caching altogether. What my system currently does is they it queries the database anytime it needs anything. I'm trying to reduce the number of queries to the DB, since the clients have awful internet connections.

```
public override IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
    int? numberOfEntities = null,
    IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = DbSet;
    List<T> result = new List<T>();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query,
            (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    var actualNumberOfEntities = Int32.MaxValue;

    if (numberOfEntities.HasValue)
    {
        actualNumberOfEntities = Math.Max(1, numberOfEntities.Value);
    }

    if (MemoryCache.Default[query.ToString()] == null)
    {        
        result = query.AsExpandable().Take(actualNumberOfEntities).ToList();
        MemoryCache.Default[query.ToString()] = result;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        result = (MemoryCache.Default[query.ToString()] as IEnumerable<T>).ToList();
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: You have to take care you are breaking an important EF desgin concept.  because you retrieve the data by find from cache and not from Db. just use Second-Level Caching https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx

Comment: You have also to control your dbContext live time, combine it with the UnitOfWork. Make the unitOfWork disposable and use it in a using scope. otherwise your DbContext First Level Cache  will caches a lot of entities and it become slow over the time and in bad use cases you will get a strange errors.

Comment: @BassamAlugili Thank you for pointing me in the right direction =)